# How to set value '0' to stackTraceOutputMethod explicitly in TestNG

Tags: testng

I don't want the complete Stacktrace to be displayed when my selenium test fails. hence I want to set the "stackTraceOutputMethod" to "0" so that it just displays the Exception class and message, not the full the stacktrace.
I read that it can be done through command line. But I want to configure it through the testng.xml or in my script. I am working on Selenium with Java on TestNG framework. So please help me in setting the value of "stackTraceOutputMethod" to "0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that if you are using Eclipse, you can set the value to "0" by following these steps:

```
1. Right click on testng.xml > Run Configurations
2. Under "Test" tab, you can see "Run Time" label > Log level (0-10) dropdown.
3. Select 0 from dropdown.
```

Thats it :)............. you will get the output as follows:
TC001 
java.lang.AssertionError: 
    at testscripts.F_TS001_.java:50)
... Removed 27 stack frames